# Error "8000401a" while C# Excel generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, excel-interop, job-scheduling

I work on a `MVC` web application. This application has `quartz.net` job that start along with the application on deployment. quartz(third party dlls) was only being used for scheduling. This scheduled job is coded on C#. This job generates excel reports and emails it to the stake holders. `Inorder` to create and write data to excel i am depending on Microsoft `Interop` Assemblies. This job now runs fine on local(development box).But when its deployed to a remote application server, it throws an exception  as follows:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the
>   configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).

Observation:
If i log onto the remote server (deployment server) at the time of excel generation, the excel gets emailed successfully. Problem occurs when i logoff from the Remote application server. I have searched for a solution, but nothing worked out. Anticipating for some direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the generation occurs on a separate windows service?

Comment: Generation code is inside the MVC application. Its a separate C# class inside the project. I use Quartz .NET for scheduling (dlls that also does the same job as a windows service). These dlls are also added to project. And on application start event, the scheduler starts and invokes the C# code (Job) on the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- extract the scheduling and the code that generates the Excel files in a separate Windows service.
- log on the new serice with Local System.

This way the service should work whether an user is logged on or not.
Make sure you give permissions to the folder where the Excel files are generated.

Comment: I understand the point, but is there a way to achieve this with out extracting the code out.